# How to make EMR cluster auto-scaling to utilize on-demand instances while staying within the max limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-emr

I have an EMR cluster created by Terraform. Here is the auto scaling policy:

```
resource "aws_emr_managed_scaling_policy" "my_aws_emr_managed_scaling_policy" {
  cluster_id = var.amazon_emr_cluster_id
  compute_limits {
    unit_type                       = "InstanceFleetUnits"
    minimum_capacity_units          = 2
    maximum_capacity_units          = 10
    maximum_ondemand_capacity_units = 2
    maximum_core_capacity_units     = 1
  }
}
```

When I check in the EMR UI, you can see everything looks correct.

[image]

Initially I got these which is expected:

- 1 on-demand primary instance
- 1 on-demand core instance
- 1 spot task instance

However, after it runs about 18 hours, the cluster auto scales to

- 1 on-demand primary instance
- 1 on-demand core instance
- 1 on-demand task instance

[image]

But I did set `maximum_ondemand_capacity_units` to 2. Also you can see from EMR UI

> To provision the primary node to use On-Demand pricing and other nodes in the cluster to use Spot pricing, set this value to 1. To provision the entire cluster to use On-Demand pricing, use the same value as your maximum cluster size.

Based on my settings, I expect I would have 1 primary on-demand instance and 1 core on-demand instance, and the rest of 1 ~ 8 task instances would be spot instances.

How can I make EMR cluster auto-scaling to utilize on-demand instances while staying within the maximum limit? In my case, it would be

- 1 on-demand primary instance
- 1 on-demand core instance
- 1 ~ 8 spot task instances

So that on-demand instances only have 2.

Thanks!

Comment: So you want the entire cluster to use on-demand capacity or not?

Comment: Hi @MarkoE I updated the title and last paragraph to make more it clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting both `MaximumOnDemandCapacityUnits` and `MaximumCoreCapacityUnits` to `1`. My guess is that, contrary to what the UI says, the `MaximumOnDemandCapacityUnits` doesn't count the master fleet instance.

The guess is based on the fact that EMR Managed Scaling resizes only core and task fleets and the description of some parameters in the documentation. Please see the relevant quote from page [ComputeLimits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/API_ComputeLimits.html) below; the emphasis is mine.

> **MinimumCapacityUnits**
>
> The lower boundary of Amazon EC2 units. It is measured through vCPU cores or instances for instance groups and measured through units for instance fleets. Managed scaling activities are not allowed beyond this boundary. *The limit only applies to the core and task nodes. The master node cannot be scaled after initial configuration.*

Also, your scenario is covered by the item five on page [Understanding node allocation strategy and scenarios](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/managed-scaling-allocation-strategy.html#node-allocation-scenarios) that suggests the same configuration.

> **Scenario 5: Scale On-Demand Instances on core nodes and Spot Instances on task nodes**
>
> To scale On-Demand Instances on core nodes and Spot Instances on task nodes, the managed scaling parameters must meet the following requirements:
>
> - The On-Demand limit must be equal to the maximum core node.
> - Both the On-Demand limit and the maximum core node must be less than the maximum boundary.